# Orderby two meta fields not working

Tags: wp-query, customization, post-meta, order

Good day.  I have the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'rc_repl_status',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'sold'
                        )
                ),
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
            'meta_key' => '_rc_repl_property_year_sold',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value _rc_repl_property_acres',
            'order' => 'DESC'
);


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

First I am filtering my post type by a taxonomy for sold properties (ranch listings).  Next I want the year they were sold first DESC order.  Next I want another meta field of acres sorted (the _rc_repl_property_acres field) also DESC order.

It sorts good with the year then breaks on the acres.

Looks like this:

RANCH A
SOLD 2014
Acres 1300

RANCH B
SOLD 2014
ACRES 1700

RANCH C
SOLD 2013
ACRES 800

RANCH D
SOLD 2013
ACRES 900

----  SHOULD BE ----

RANCH B
SOLD 2014
ACRES 1700

RANCH A
SOLD 2014
ACRES 1300

RANCH D
SOLD 2013
ACRES 900

RANCH C
SOLD 2013
ACRES 800

Hope this makes sense...  Please help!

Answer (score 1):

SPECIAL THANKS TO THIS ARTICLE: http://dotnordic.se/sorting-wordpress-posts-by-several-numeric-custom-fields/

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'rc_repl_status',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'sold'
    )
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => 100,
  'meta_key' => '_rc_repl_property_year_sold',
  'meta_query'  => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_rc_repl_property_year_sold' // do this to order by two meta field VALUES
    ),
    array(
       'key' => '_rc_repl_property_acres', // do this to order by two meta field VALUES
    ),
   ),
);

// do this to order by two meta field VALUES - This takes generic values and
// can be used with any WP_Query meta_query
function customorderby($orderby) {
  return 'mt1.meta_value DESC, mt2.meta_value+0 DESC';
}

// Now apply your filter. Add it before your query and remove it 
// afterwards to make sure it doesn’t affect subsequent queries.
add_filter('posts_orderby','customorderby');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter('posts_orderby','customorderby');
```